Dynamic listener AWS LOad Balancer
i want to create a PaaS mechanism where users can apply their own domain into our app.
Use Case :
we have a general domain customer.test.com
The user could apply their own domain into customer.test.com using a CNAME.
example :
CNAME handsome.me -> customer.test.com

AWS Load Balancer requires creating a listener that will point to the target group.
I'm also using the Elastic BeanStalk.
Issue :

There is a limitation for creating the Listener around 200 per Load Balancer.
SSL (i can using free SSL from AWS)

the goal for this is to make user able to point into our shared app using their own domain, anytime anywhere.
definitely, it'll solved using the VPS, but we need the auto-scale one.
and I have no clue how to make this happen.
Please advice
